# Bootstrapping for time series modeling

Tags: time-series, bootstrap, uncertainty

I am developing a model to decompose a univariate time series dataset into three components: seasonal, trend, and a piecewise semi-linear component with a sawtooth pattern (repeated gradual decline and sudden recovery). These components are known to be **multiplicative**. For now, let us ignore what kind of methods I use to find these components. After decomposing the signal, **I need to estimate the uncertainty of my model**. This is what I am getting at.

I found one paper that does something similar: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S037722171830081X?via%3Dihub
Although the paper really is about bagging for time series forecasting, I believe the bootstrapping part is relevant for my case.

What I am doing at the moment, which is inspired by this paper, is: 
1.  Fit the model to the data
2.  Let residuals = original data / fitted model
3.  Assuming that these residuals are stationary (which they seem to be, by the look of it): Generate bootstrapped residuals with circular block bootstrapping
4.  Generate bootstrap samples: bootstrap sample = fitted model * bootstrapped residuals
5.  Fit the model on each of the bootstrap samples
6.  Calculate confidence intervals based on the results in 5

The problem with the above approach, as I see it, is that **model uncertainty is not addressed**. In other words: All the bootstrap samples will be biased by my initially fitted model. If this model is biased in some way, this bias will carry over to all the bootstrap samples. **How should I deal with this?**

In the paper, this problem is apparently dealt with by allowing different versions of the model to be fitted to the bootstrap samples. However, I don't see how this eliminates the bias introduced in the initial fit, at least in my case. Perhaps the solution would be to initially fit several different versions of my model, and then to generate bootstrap samples based on all of these fits.

In the end, I am looking for advice on how to estimate the uncertainty of my model, including data uncertainty and model uncertainty.